# Simulation issue for TI-OPA333

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is there any alternative device to replace OPA333? I can't find it in my simulation. Is there any DIP-8 chip layout so I can fix in my breadboard for testing? What should be the solution for linear or analog devices?

Comment: Can't you just add the appropriate SPICE model(s) to your simulation software? http://www.ti.com/product/OPA333/toolssoftware

Comment: How to do it in Multi-sim.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have revealed you are using Multsim from NI, I'll point you to the page on [adding](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/2373E75D8B375EA1862575D2004D9C88) SPICE models to Multisim, and to the [SPICE models for your OPA333](http://ti.com/product/OPA333/toolssoftware).

Comment: thank Spehro, last night i watched youtube how to add new model in multi-sim.